# Prove that the equation $a^2+ 2a−3 =b^2$ does not have a solution in positive integers $a$ and $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the equation $a^2+ 2a−3 =b^2$ does not have a solution in positive integers.

I have tried proving this by contradiction but I can't get to work. Can someone please help me understand how to prove this and how to write this proof?

Comment: Show your efforts in your question...

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here is a mini tutorial on how to type in MathJax in MSE. Please refer for the same to format your questions in the future. Moreover, please show all your ideas as well as your efforts (all your work) in the question.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Assume that there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ satisfying your requirements. Then:
$$a^2+2a+1-4 = b^2 \implies (a+1)^2-4=b^2$$
Thus, if $x=a+1$ and $y=b$, then $x^2-y^2=4$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. Can you see why this is impossible?

Comment: +1 If the OP needs a further hint: *$y^2+4$ is too close to a square to be a square itself.*

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, one finds that the problem can be reduced to a statement regarding $x,y$ as being positive integers, and $x^{2}-y^{2}=4$.

Then $(x+y)(x-y)=4$. If $x+y,x-y = 2$, then $x+y=x-y \implies y=-y \implies y = 0 $ which is not positive.

Clearly $x+y > x-y$ so that the other case is $x+y =4$ and $x-y = 1$.

Subtracting these equations $(x+y)-(x-y)= 2y =3 \implies y = \frac{3}{2}.$

Therefore there are no positive integer solutions.